# What would be the easiest way to get the words ordered the same

Tags: html, css

[The Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKLSP.jpg)

[My Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlzNr.jpg)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(30, 38%, 92%);
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Fraunces;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 350px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.text-container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 1px 15px 15px 1px;
  height: 900px;
  text-align: justify;
}

img {
  border-radius: 15px 1px 1px 15px;
}

button {
  background-color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 550px;
}

span.price1 {
  color: hsl(158, 36%, 37%);
  font-weight: 500;
}

span.price2 {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
}

p.body {
  color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

h3 {
  color: hsl(228, 12%, 48%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: Fraunces;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="images\image-product-desktop.jpg" alt="product-image">
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
      <h3>perfume</h3>
      <h1 class="heading">Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
      <p class="body">A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
      <p class="price1">$149.99<span>$169.99</span></p>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button" name="button"><img src="images\icon-cart.svg" alt="cart-icon">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

So i'm trying to build this card using HTML and CSS and I can't seem to get the wording to be in the order of the original. I have tried flex box method as well as other various methods such as as using margin, line breaks and padding as well as letter-spacing to get it looking similar. I hope I was able to convey the issue I am having.

Comment: you posted same image twice. what is the issue?

Comment: That was an error, I replaced it

Comment: Do you want the text to break at the same places? in the original design it seems to be a fixed width rectangle. so just experiment with a fixed width then set the other params accordingly. Of course each screen size may have its own size of width using media queries.